# how to get the exit status of the each task in ansible

Tags: ansible

1. I have 3 task in my ansible yml file as below.

   ```
   ---

     - name: Instance provisioning
       local_action:
         module: ec2
         region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
         key_name: "{{ ec2_keypair }}"
         instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
         image: "{{ ec2_image}}"
         zone: "{{ public_az }}"
         volumes:
           - device_name: "{{ device }}"
             volume_type: "{{ instance_volumetype }}"
             volume_size: "{{ volume }}"
             delete_on_termination: "{{ state }}"
         instance_tags:
           Name: "{{ instance_name }}_{{ release_name }}_APACHE"
           environment: "{{ env_type }}"
         vpc_subnet_id: "{{ public_id }}"
         assign_public_ip: "{{ public_ip_assign }}"
         group_id: "{{ sg_apache }},{{ sg_internal }}"
         wait: "{{ wait_type }}"
       register: ec2

     - name: adding group to inventory file
       lineinfile:
         dest: "/etc/ansible/hosts"
         regexp: "^\\[{{ release_name }}\\]"
         line: "[{{ release_name }}]"
         state: present

     - name: adding apache ip to hosts
       lineinfile:
         dest: "/etc/ansible/hosts"
         line: "{{ item.private_ip }} name=apache dns={{ item.public_dns_name }}
       with_items: ec2.instances
   ```

   Now i want to check the exit status of each task whether it is success or failure.
2. If any one of the task fails my other task should not execute.

Please advice how to write an ansible playbook

Answer (score 2):

In your first task, you have register the output to ec2.
now use fail module to stop the play if the task fails.

Ex.

```
register: ec2

fail:
   when: "ec2.rc == 1"
```

here rc is the return code of the command .. we are assuming 1 for fail and 0 for success.

use fail module after every task.

Let me know if it works for you ..

Answer (score 1):

Register a variable in each task and then check it in the next task.  See http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_tests.html#task-results

Comment: Why would you do that when failing a playbook after a failed task is already the default behavior?

Comment: Although the playbook doesn't include it he could very easily want to include a "failed_when: False" to task so that failed tasks continue.  That would be a reason.  You don't always want a playbook to fail when a task fails.  In fact if you design your playbooks well you probably never want that to happen

Comment: That is completely the opposite of what he is asking, since he does want the entire playbook to fail if a task fails. It's also incredibly bad practice. You almost always do want to stop if you hit a failure, because it means that it is impossible to reach the state that you declared. If there is some cleanup you need to do after failure, you would use Error handling in blocks to execute that.

Comment: Well I made the assumption they ran the playbook and saw it failed when a task failed. I extrapolated from there.  Your "incredibly bad practice" comment holds no water especially given it's included in the language.  Not every tasks declares a state...this isn't SaltStack.  If you aren't on ansible 2.0 you don't have error blocks.  Furthermore there are many instances you want to ignore errors.  A perfect example if you're using the shell to gather information.  Any non zero exit status will be zero, but that may be exactly what you're looking for (the non-zero status) to make a decision.

Comment: I'm not saying it's incredibly bad practice to use it at all, though it should be avoided where possible. I'm saying that it's bad practice to do it as much as possible, which is what you seemed to imply by saying "you probably never want that [exiting the playbook in case of an error] to happen"

Also, people are unlikely to be writing new playbooks on pre-2.0 at this point.

Comment: peace on it not being ideal to do all the time.  I hope people aren't writing playbook to run on pre-2.0 code however if you're using the Python API moving to 2.0 isn't quite so easy.  Complete refactoring in 2.0 means a lot of potential work.  If you're just writing playbooks though I agree

Answer (score 1):

This is already the default behavior in Ansible. If a task fails, the Playbook aborts and reports the failure. You don't need to build in any extra functionality around this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [playbook blocks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_blocks.html) and it's error handling is to help you?

Comment: hi all , since i'm beginner to ansible really not getting quick idea when i go through the links ,hence pls share a sample example for my better understand.

Answer (score 0):

Kumar

if You want to check each task output if it is success or failure do this,

```
---

  - name: Instance provisioning
    local_action:
      module: ec2
      region: "{{ vpc_region }}"
      key_name: "{{ ec2_keypair }}"
      instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
      image: "{{ ec2_image}}"
      zone: "{{ public_az }}"
      volumes:
        - device_name: "{{ device }}"
          volume_type: "{{ instance_volumetype }}"
          volume_size: "{{ volume }}"
          delete_on_termination: "{{ state }}"
      instance_tags:
        Name: "{{ instance_name }}_{{ release_name }}_APACHE"
        environment: "{{ env_type }}"
      vpc_subnet_id: "{{ public_id }}"
      assign_public_ip: "{{ public_ip_assign }}"
      group_id: "{{ sg_apache }},{{ sg_internal }}"
      wait: "{{ wait_type }}"
    register: ec2

  - name: adding group to inventory file
    lineinfile:
      dest: "/etc/ansible/hosts"
      regexp: "^\\[{{ release_name }}\\]"
      line: "[{{ release_name }}]"
      state: present
    when: ec2 | changed
    register: fileoutput 

  - name: adding apache ip to hosts
    lineinfile:
      dest: "/etc/ansible/hosts"
      line: "{{ item.private_ip }} name=apache dns={{ item.public_dns_name }}
    with_items: ec2.instances
    when: fileoutput | changed
```

In your code register a variable in each and every Task if The Task has Changed to True, The Followed Task will execute otherwise it will skip that Task.